# Extjs: Want to set decription on a condition if any field "abc"(can be accesed by data.abc) is coming from backend

Tags: javascript, extjs

Description is given in .js as:

```
 viewModel: {
            data: {
                description: 'xyz',
            }
```

It is defined as

```
 {
                xtype: 'component',
                margin: '0 0 15 10',
                bind: {
                    html: '{description}',
                   }
```

> I want to set this description with the value coming from a label
> from backend..which can be accesed as data.abc. But its not working
> when using directly in description.

Comment: Please include more from your code, how do you set this value in ViewModel, how do you assign the ViewModel to your View etc. It should word with the code you already posted if it is set up correctly.

Comment: I fully second @Peter_Koltai. Could you send us the controller too, so that we can see how you add the description in the first place - or is it hard coded, then you can add new data like this: [CONTROLLER] this.getViewModel().set('description', 'abc')